# How to custom Java Spring GET match all routes except "/api" and "/swagger-ui"

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, routes

I'm setting up the controller to match all routes and return the built production React. While doing that I couldn't do GET APIs from http://localhost:8080/api/ (Return the blank screen of React) when the POST method works fine. Any suggestion on how to make React match all routes except "/api", please?

My Controller Code

```
@Controller
public class ClientForwardController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/**/{path:[^\\.]*}")
    public String forward() { 
        return "forward:/";
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a separate API controller `@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
class ApiController {...}`

Comment: I have created it, and the POST APIs in that controller work fine.

Comment: Then you need to add a configuration that will tune the path matching precedence. The [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html) has an explanation and example. The direct link doesn't work, but it is in section 1.12.12 of the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to this question.

I've added SwaggerController.java controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/docs")
public class SwaggerController {
    @GetMapping
    public String index() {
        return "redirect:/swagger-ui/index.html";
    }
}
```

The point is to override the
"/**" matching in the previous controller I wrote above in the question.

And with the API endpoints ("/api"), I had a mistake to put GetMapping("/") for that controller so it has to write ("/api/something/something/") to match [I wrote "/api/something/something"]. So all the problems were fixed.